# Rails Active Record join query with sorting and limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, left-join, inner-join

I’m trying to put together a reasonably complex Active Record query and I’m fairly new to Rails.

### Relationships

Here are the relevant model relationships for the query:

- **Teams** can have many **Users**.
- Users have a **team_id** column to track which team they’re in.
- Teams have a single admin, which is a user. This is in an **admin_id** column on a team.
- Users have an email address (e.g. foo@example.com).

### Schema

Here are the relevant portions of `schema.rb`:

```
create_table "teams", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "admin_id"
end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "email", default: "", null: false
  t.integer "team_id"
end

add_foreign_key "teams", "users", column: "admin_id"
add_foreign_key "users", "teams"
```

### Query

Given a **domain name** (e.g. example.com), I would like to find teams that have admins with an email address with that domain name. If there are multiple matches, I would like only the team with the most users. Here’s what I have so far:

```
team = Team.joins('INNER JOIN users ON admin_id = users.id')
           .where('email LIKE ?', "%example.com")
           .where(domain_sign_up: true)
```

### Problem

The problem with this query is that it returns all matches as an array. I would like to order it by `team.users.count`, then return only the first one (with the most users) team as an object, not an array. Is this perhaps a candidate for a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer posted by Ursus was quite useful, however I ended up adding a new column to **team** called domain to simplify things, then used `.left_join` to order by users. Here’s my final query:

```
team = Team.left_joins(:users)
           .where(domain: 'example.com', domain_sign_up: true)
           .group('teams.id')
           .order('COUNT(users.id) DESC')
           .first
```

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this

```
team = Team.joins('INNER JOIN users ON admin_id = users.id')
           .where('email LIKE ?', "%example.com")
           .where(domain_sign_up: true)
           .group('teams.id')
           .select('teams.*, COUNT(users.id) AS team_users_count')
           .order('COUNT(users.id) DESC')
           .first
```

I changed `limit(1)` to `first`. It doesn't seem to have much sense `limit` if the parameter is 1, so you have a `Team`, not a relation of one team.

Comment: That looks great! I'll try it out today. Thank you! Are there any serious performance implications with a query like this?

Comment: Nope, I say there aren't. I mean, it's just a single SQL query and it has nothing particularly slow to me. If you are worried about it try an explain and eventually add some indexes on your tables

Comment: I tried this out and it's not quite doing what I expect. I have three teams in my local database – #1 has **two users** including an admin with example.com, #2 has **one user**, an admin with foo.com, and #3 has **one user**, an admin with example.com. This query always returns team #3, even if I change `DESC` to `ASC` or `.first` to `.last`, when it should return #1 since it has more users. If I drop `.first`, then I get an array with team #1 and team #3.

Comment: Okay, so I ended up creating a domain column on team, and then using `.left_joins` on user to order by the user count.

Comment: Oh, I see the problem. I missed that part where you join only admin users.